# Open second View like NavigationLink onRecive()

Tags: ios, view, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Hello i try to open a new view in the same pattern of the NavigationLink by receiving a notification.

```
var body: some View {
    return VStack {
        WebView(webPageURL:webPageURL).onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .viewNotificationMessage)) { notification in

            let message = notification.object as? String ?? ""
            if(message == "Show"){
                //Open her SecoundView like NavigationLink
            }
        }
        NavigationLink(destination: SecoundView()) {
            Text("Do Something")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
@State private var isActive = false
var body: some View {
    return VStack {
        WebView(webPageURL:webPageURL).onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .viewNotificationMessage)) { notification in

            let message = notification.object as? String ?? ""
            if(message == "Show"){
                self.isActive = true // activate the link below
            }
        }.background(
           NavigationLink(destination: SecoundView(), isActive: $isActive) {
            EmptyView()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution looks good for now. But I want to remove the NavigationLink from the View. But this is not possible with this solution.
I try to start the view "SecoundView" so that it behaves like the NavigationLink.

Comment: @TheBuro. What do you mean by *like NavigationLink*? If you want just remove it for user, but have same behaviour, then see updated.

Comment: Ok its looks better with the updated code part.
I mean behavior with the fact that a new view opens from the side. And there is an arrow above.